# I can't post code on Stack Overflow. What can I do?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

How can I post this code on Stack Overflow?

http://pastebin.com/7ph5GKRV

Comment: Don't post the code here please.

Comment: That's entirely too much code to post in a single question on Stack Overflow. Identify the **smallest example** that illustrates your problem, and post that.

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste like normal text. You can then select it and click the `{}` button to make it formatted as source code (indents all code by 4 space/1 tab)

```
<h1>this is HTML code</h1>
<p>it is not intpreted by the browser, but shown verbatim</p>
```